# Segfault in fuerte stageros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm seeing a consistent segfault in stageros on startup seemingly related to blocks.  If I remove the block portion of the robot definition it does load but the robot doesn't get hit by laser strikes.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, and am seeing the same crashes on computers with both AMD and Nvidia GPU's.

The following gdb output was generated while trying to run the roomba_stage tutorial at: https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/tutorials/file/d1f3dda4fd5a/roomba_stage

The segfault occurs in:  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so

```
Starting program: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/bin/stageros /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x42720b40 (LWP 7706)]
[New Thread 0x42921b40 (LWP 7707)]
[New Thread 0x42d00b40 (LWP 7708)]
[New Thread 0x43200b40 (LWP 7715)]
[New Thread 0x4516db40 (LWP 7719)]
 [Loading /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world][New Thread 0x45bcab40 (LWP 7720)]
[Image "./maps/lse_arena.pgm"]
warn: worldfile /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world:22 : property [laser_return] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
warn: worldfile /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world:32 : property [color] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
warn: worldfile /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world:8 : property [range_max] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
warn: worldfile /home/ros/fuerte_workspace/navigation_tutorials/roomba_stage/roomba_lse_arena.world:7 : property [range_min] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
[ INFO] [1350446716.598520044]: found 1 position/laser pair in the file
[New Thread 0x45dcbb40 (LWP 7727)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4097c793 in __gl_pqSortInit (pq=0x843f9f8) at libtess/priorityq.c:132
132       j = r + 1;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4097c793 in __gl_pqSortInit (pq=0x843f9f8) at libtess/priorityq.c:132
#1  0x4097fb2e in InitPriorityQ (tess=) at libtess/sweep.c:1251
#2  __gl_computeInterior (tess=0x8666078) at libtess/sweep.c:1321
#3  0x40980900 in gluTessEndPolygon (tess=0x8666078) at libtess/tess.c:540
#4  0x40273d55 in Stg::BlockGroup::BuildDisplayList (this=0x864a6d4) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/blockgroup.cc:243
#5  0x40274155 in Stg::BlockGroup::CallDisplayList (this=0x864a6d4) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/blockgroup.cc:288
#6  0x4028857e in Stg::Model::DrawBlocks (this=0x864a678) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/model_draw.cc:253
#7  0x402889b2 in Stg::Model::DrawBlocksTree (this=0x864a678) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/model_draw.cc:235
#8  0x402adc73 in Stg::Canvas::DrawBlocks (this=0x80bbfd0) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/canvas.cc:717
#9  0x402b5950 in Stg::Canvas::renderFrame (this=0x80bbfd0) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/canvas.cc:954
#10 0x402ad7e1 in Stg::Canvas::draw (this=0x80bbfd0) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/canvas.cc:1321
#11 0x40a74197 in Fl_Gl_Window::flush() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfltk_gl.so.1.1
#12 0x405e6ee3 in Fl::flush() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfltk.so.1.1
#13 0x405e8645 in Fl::wait(double) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfltk.so.1.1
#14 0x08059209 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff004) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/src/stageros.cpp:445

(gdb) info locals
p = 0x8666f20
r = 0x8666f5c
i = 0x8666f5c
j = 0x8666f60
piv = 0x8666eb8
Stack = {{p = 0x8666f20, r = 0x8666f5c}, {p = 0xbfffe6b8, r = 0x404912c1}, {p = 0x866f600, r = 0x43337ff4}, {p = 0x41018899, r = 0x404912c1}, {p = 0x82e3de0, r = 0xb}, {p = 0x80cdd50, r = 0x404912c1}, {
    p = 0x268, r = 0x2710}, {p = 0x48, r = 0x405c0470}, {p = 0x405c0478, r = 0x9}, {p = 0x40, r = 0x9}, {p = 0x3d8, r = 0x2710}, {p = 0x40, r = 0x405c0470}, {p = 0x405c0478, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x3c, r = 0x8}, {
    p = 0x1, r = 0x50}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x404912c1}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x8, r = 0x39}, {p = 0x5b, r = 0x6e}, {p = 0x77, r = 0x404912c1}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x30}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x405bfff4}, {p = 0x0, 
    r = 0x2710}, {p = 0x110, r = 0x405c0470}, {p = 0x5b, r = 0x6e}, {p = 0x108, r = 0x22}, {p = 0x4, r = 0x2710}, {p = 0x88, r = 0x405c0470}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x80, r = 0x11}, {p = 0x2, r = 0x98}, {
    p = 0x0, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x11, r = 0x3a}, {p = 0x5b, r = 0x6e}, {p = 0x77, r = 0x7c}, {p = 0x8660000, r = 0x86654c0}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x405bfff4}, {p = 0x405c0440, r = 0x4097a520}, {
    p = 0x80, r = 0x40493fec}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x0}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x409d0ff4}, {p = 0x86652c0, r = 0x8666d00}, {p = 0x866f484, r = 0x4097c20a}, {p = 0x108, r = 0x3ff00000}, {p = 0x0, r = 0x4097c993}, {
    p = 0x843f9f8, r = 0x4097a520}, {p = 0x86652c0, r = 0x4097c5a0}, {p = 0x80, r = 0x3fc51eb8}, {p = 0x2e5096af, r = 0xdf238d35}}
top = 
seed = 1409832680
(gdb) up
#1  0x4097fb2e in InitPriorityQ (tess=) at libtess/sweep.c:1251
1251      if (v != vHead || !pqInit( pq ) ) { /* __gl_pqSortInit */
(gdb) info locals
pq = 0x843f9f8
v = 0x866f430
vHead = 0x866f430
(gdb) up
#2  __gl_computeInterior (tess=0x8666078) at libtess/sweep.c:1321
1321      if ( !InitPriorityQ( tess ) ) return 0; /* if error */
(gdb) info locals
v = 
vNext = 
(gdb) up
#3  0x40980900 in gluTessEndPolygon (tess=0x8666078) at libtess/tess.c:540
540   if ( !__gl_computeInterior( tess ) ) {
(gdb) info locals
mesh = 
(gdb) up
#4  0x40273d55 in Stg::BlockGroup::BuildDisplayList (this=0x864a6d4) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/blockgroup.cc:243
243 /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/blockgroup.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info locals
tobj = 0x8666078
geom = {pose = {_vptr.Pose = 0x8071dd8, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, a = 0}, size = {x = 0.33000000000000002, y = 0.33000000000000002, z = 0.10000000000000001}}
contours = { >, std::allocator > > >> = {
    _M_impl = { > >> = { > >> = {}, }, 
      _M_start = 0x866aee8, _M_finish = 0x866aef4, _M_end_of_storage = 0x866aef4}}, }
c =
```

Is this a known bug?  I cannot find this particular crash in the bug trackers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46049/segfault-in-fuerte-stageros/) by [kbogert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3398/kbogert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kbogert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3398/kbogert/) on 2012-10-17**:
This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the rangers issue in:  http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/?answer=34967#post-id-34967

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-17**:
Do other world files launch without issue?

**Comment by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) on 2012-10-18**:
Yes it has to do with rangers. Your world file define a laser but in stage 4.0 there are no more laser devices. They are all rangers now.

**Comment by [kbogert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3398/kbogert/) on 2012-10-19**:
I've tried other worlds and they have the same issue.  Pablo stop, if you'd look at the world file I'm launching you'd see that it has changed all the Laser's to Rangers.

**Comment by [kbogert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3398/kbogert/) on 2012-10-19**:
Note that if I run stage with the -g option to disable graphics this crash is avoided

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-19**:
to be clear, you're using an NVIDIA card and this isn't a virtual card correct?

**Comment by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) on 2012-10-21**:
It would be easier to help you if you post hear your world file, of course.  But I can see 4 warning messages in your trace that are related to the new syntax for lasers.  I recommend you to fix them just to be sure that the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the problem is that in the stage world files the block sections are missing the z parameter.  See: https:  //github.com/rtv/Stage/issues/31

So I prevented the crash by adding:

```
z [0 .32]
```

to the stage world file's block section linked in the original question up top.

---

Originally posted by [kbogert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3398/kbogert/) with karma: 26 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0